# could static members use nonstatic members and vice versa?

Tags: php, oop, class

could i use nonstatic members inside a static method?

eg.

```
 $this->nonStaticProperty
 $this->nonStaticMethod()
```

and vice versa that is to say use static members inside non-static methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

You can't use non-static members in a static function, since they're outside the function's scope. But you can use static members in a non-static function.

Answer (score 3):

As a static member doesn't have an instance, it can't call instance methods (unless you create an instance inside that method).

Comment: is creating an instance within a static method recommended?

Comment: no, it's not; if you need to do that, you have a design problem

Answer (score 0):

Not really, as you can't use $this in a static context.

Answer (score 0):

```
class foo {
    
      
    
    public static function bar()
    {
        echo "bar calling\n";
    }
    
}



$ff = new foo();
echo $ff->bar();

echo foo::bar();
```

Check here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48b9540c8d897f46dcd8ea13595950fa78fa96e5