# Private vs Private Static

Tags: php

I always use `private $MyVar = false;` when declaring **private variables** which only that specific class can use. But recently i saw some examples where people use `private static $MyVar = false;`.

I don't get it, what's the difference? Both of them can only be used inside that class, so whats the point in adding `static`?

Comment: A `static` class property is always the same value for all instances of the class, and even exists if there are no instances (when it can be accessed from static methods) - [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) It has no connection with visibility (private/public/protected) at all

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957629/how-to-access-a-private-member-inside-a-static-function-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Please post answers as answers and not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

1. A private instance variable named `x`:

   ```
   class Foo {
       private $x = 0;
       public function Foo() {
           echo ++$this->x . ',';
       }
   }

   new Foo();
   new Foo();
   ```

   The output is `1,1,`.
2. A private static variable named `x`:

   ```
   class Bar {
       private static $x = 0;
       public function Bar() {
           echo ++self::$x . ',';
       }
   }

   new Bar();
   new Bar();
   ```

   The output is `1,2,`.