# PHP: Controller not working

Tags: php, laravel

This is a controller I just made that will check the input password. It's seemed to be no mistakes. But, when I run it, it didn't receive the result (echo "Right password") although I entered the right input.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MainController extends Controller
{
private $data = array(
    array("TestUser","Password"),
    array("Admin","BigA1r")
);
//$this->log($u,$p);    
public static function log($username,$pass) { //login
    echo "<title>Processing request...</title>";
    echo "Logging in... Please wait.";
    for ($i = 1;$i == 35;$i++){
            $u = $data[$i][1];
            if ($u == $username){
                $p = $data[$i][2];
                if ($p == $pass){
                    setcookie("username="+$u);//+";password="+p;
                    echo "Right password";
                }else{echo "Wrong password";};
            }else{
                echo "Can't find this username. Please try a different 
name.";
            }       
    }   
}
```

What's the mistake here? I can't find it. And it didn't throw any. It just stopped at echo "Logging in... Please wait.";

Comment: Could you please explain what you really want to do because your question is not pretty clear at least to me. Why there is static function and how you are calling it..? Show your routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues in your code like,

1. Use `self::$data` instead of `$data`. Read [How to access private variable in static function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957641/1817690)
2. Loop Condition to `count(self::$data)`
3. Undefined index issue for password, as Indexing starts from 0

So, try the below code

```
for ($i = 0,$l=count(self::$data);$i < $l;$i++){
   $u = self::$data[$i][0]; // use 0 not 1 for username, as index start from 0
   if ($u == $username){
       $p = self::$data[$i][1]; // use 1 not 2, as index start from 0
       if ($p == $pass){
          setcookie("username="+$u);//+";password="+p;
          echo "Right password";
       } else{echo "Wrong password";};
   } else{
       echo "Can't find this username. Please try a different name.";
   }       
} //end for
```

And make your private variable `$data` to be `static` like,

```
private static $data = array(
    array("TestUser","Password"),
    array("Admin","BigA1r")
);
```

Full code,

```
class MainController extends Controller {
    private static $data = array(
        array("TestUser","Password"),
        array("Admin","BigA1r")
    );
    //$this->log($u,$p);    
    public static function log($username,$pass) { //login
        echo "<title>Processing request...</title>";
        echo "Logging in... Please wait.";
        for ($i = 0,$l=count(self::$data);$i < $l;$i++){
            $u = self::$data[$i][0];
            if ($u == $username){
                $p = self::$data[$i][1];
                if ($p == $pass){
                    setcookie("username="+$u);//+";password="+p;
                    echo "Right password";
                } else {
                    echo "Wrong password";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Can't find this username. Please try a different name.";
            }
        } // end for loop  
    } // end function log
} // end class MainController
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
self::$data[$i][1] and self::$data[$i][2]
```

To access a private variable of a class from static method you need to use self keyword.

Also, in the loop you have

```
for ($i = 1;$i == 35;$i++)
```

This might fail running as the condition is $i==35 and your are starting with $i=1 which is never satisfied it should be $i<=35.

Comment: that's great !!